# "on" not binding to dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery

My HTML

```
<div>    
    <span  class="more-available" data-completeMessage="This is the complete message you see after clicking more">Hello</span>​
</div>
```

I add a anchor tag to the end dynamically and then want to attach a click handler to the anchor tag. So I do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   //Attach future proof click event to an anchor tag
   $('a.more').on('click', function() {
      var $parent = $(this).parent();
      $parent.text($parent.data('completemessage'));
   });

   //Add the anchor tag
   $('span.more-available').append($('<a class="more">...more</a>'));
});;​
```

This does not work. **If i replace "on" by "live" it works**. (but live is depreciated)

I know I can do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div').on('click','a.more', function() {
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        $parent.text($parent.data('completemessage'));
    });

    $('span.more-available').append($('<a class="more">...more</a>'));
});;​
```

and it works, but my question is...

Was I wrong in assuming that "on" provides all the functionality of live? Does "on" not bind to future elements?  Is this correct behavior, or am I doing something wrong.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arishlabroo/pRBke/5/

Comment: I believe you will need to go higher one level for `on` to work similarly to live, due to the event bubbling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`on()` is just a binder that allows for target delegation. It's more of a replacement for `delegate()` than for `live()`.

`$('foo').live('click',fn);` is essentially `$(document).on('click','foo',fn);`

With that in mind, you simply bind the click event to the constant parent wrapper and delegate to your target, like so:

```
$('span.more-available').on('click', 'a.more', function(){
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.text($parent.data('completemessage'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it like below,

```
$('span.more-available').on('click', 'a.more', function () {
   //..your code
});
```

You cannot just replace replace `.live` with `.on` instead you need to bind the handler to the parent element with the specific selector meaning the handle will be delegated when the event is triggered for the matching selector. In above, the you are adding a listener to `span.more-available` which will execute the handler only when the matching selector `a.more` is triggered.

In short follow the two steps to replace `.live` with `.on`,

1. Find the closest parent elements to which the element will be added dynamically.
2. Bind the handler to parent element with the dynamic elements selector as the 2nd argument.

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for the `$.live()` method:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

The documentation for `$.live()` further goes on to show us the methods and syntax to use for the successors of this method:

> Rewriting the .live() method in terms of its successors is straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all three event attachment methods:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

If you're using jQuery 1.7 or greater, use the `$.on()` method as instructed above.

Comment: I don't see how this answer is any more helpful than the two previous answers, especially since it merely recites the jquery docs.

Comment: @PHPBree We may disagree, but I think it's *very* helpful to teach people how to read the relevant documentation.

Comment: This is a slippery slope. A simple link to the docs in a comment would have sufficed. It's a basic DRY approach - send the users to jquery.com to read the docs there. Users who give thoughtful answers should receive upvotes, not users who copy/paste documentation without much else.

Comment: @PHPBree You're free to vote as you see fit. I personally feel the answer is acceptable, and had I been the OP I wouldn't mind somebody referencing and citing the relevant documentation.